# any way to access variables from within post editor?

Tags: posts, editor

I am trying to assign a variable either from my template file or otherwise which I can then access within the post editor.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean specifically by "access within post editor"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in mechanism to access php in the post editor. The best solution would be to create a [custom shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) which you can use to access the variable. This is probably the safest and most secure method available.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't been too descriptive but if you mean that you would be able to edit a variable in the Post > Edit screen then you should really be using [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields). These variables would be stored / retrieved as post meta-data.